# TypeAhead different widgets flutter

Tags: flutter, typeahead

I'm trying to create different widgets in TypeAhead suggestion depends on `suggestion.subName.length`
1. ListTile with a subTitle
2. ListTile without subTitle

```
TypeAhead(
... 
 itemBuilder: (context, suggestion) {
        return ListTile(
          dense: true,
          title: AutoSizeText(
            suggestion.primeName,
            maxLines: 1,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            minFontSize: 20,
          ),
          subtitle: suggestion.subName.length == 0 ? null:AutoSizeText(
            suggestion.subName.join(', '),
            maxLines: 1,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            minFontSize: 15,
          ),
        );
      },
...
```

But everything comes back with a subtitle.
What could cause that? Is it possible to make 2 different types of widgets in TypeAhead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
I use the following example to simulate this case 
You can return `Container()` not `null`

```
subtitle: suggestion.subName.length == 0 ? Container() : AutoSizeText(
```

or put condition in `itemBuilder`, for more complex condition you can use if

```
itemBuilder: (context, suggestion) {
     return suggestion.subName.length == 0 ? ListTile(...) : ListTile(...);
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter_typeahead/flutter_typeahead.dart';

class BackendService {
  static Future<List> getSuggestions(String query) async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));

    return List.generate(3, (index) {
      return {'name': query + index.toString(), 'price': Random().nextInt(100)};
    });
  }
}

class CitiesService {
  static final List<String> cities = [
    'Beirut',
    'Damascus',
    'San Fransisco',
    'Rome',
    'Los Angeles',
    'Madrid',
    'Bali',
    'Barcelona',
    'Paris',
    'Bucharest',
    'New York City',
    'Philadelphia',
    'Sydney',
  ];

  static List<String> getSuggestions(String query) {
    List<String> matches = List();
    matches.addAll(cities);

    matches.retainWhere((s) => s.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase()));
    return matches;
  }
}

class NavigationExample extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            height: 10.0,
          ),
          TypeAheadField(
            textFieldConfiguration: TextFieldConfiguration(
              autofocus: true,
              style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context)
                  .style
                  .copyWith(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  hintText: 'What are you looking for?'),
            ),
            suggestionsCallback: (pattern) async {
              return await BackendService.getSuggestions(pattern);
            },
            itemBuilder: (context, suggestion) {
              return ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
                title: Text(suggestion['name']),
                subtitle: suggestion['price'] < 20
                    ? Container()
                    : Text('\$${suggestion['price']}'),
              );
            },
            onSuggestionSelected: (suggestion) {
              Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => ProductPage(product: suggestion)));
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ProductPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final Map<String, dynamic> product;

  ProductPage({this.product});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text(
              this.product['name'],
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline,
            ),
            Text(
              this.product['price'].toString() + ' USD',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            NavigationExample(),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: it is not working, neither for the leading property.
Even in the picture, you can tell there is an empty subtitle